# On/Off switch (redefine a macro at each use)

Tags: macros, fun

I try do define a macro `\onoff`, which alternatively prints "on" and "off" each time it's used. For example the sequence `\onoff \onoff \onoff` would print `on off on`

My first guess would be to use the following code:

```
\def\a{on}
\def\b{off}    
\newcommand\onoff{\a\def\c{\a}\def\a{\b}\def\b{\c}}
```

However this code doesn't work. Is there an elegant way to code this?

Comment: now I can reveal that you were quite close to a working solution: `\def\onoff{\a\let\c\a\let\a\b\let\b\c}` in your set-up works.

Comment: @jfbu, in this simple case, I think that `\edef` would do as well.

Comment: Laurent, I am sure that you know, but of course the problem is that `\def\c{\a}` says "define `\c` to expand to `\a`" (thus eventually to the *future* contents of `\a`), not "… to the (current) contents of `\a`".  `\let` essentially says the latter.  `\edef` expands macros at definition time rather than use time, which is why it would also work here.

Comment: @LSpice yes, totally true.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One way

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@ONoff {on\let\onoff\@onOFF}
\def\@onOFF {off\let\onoff\@ONoff}
\let\onoff\@ONoff
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\onoff\onoff\onoff\onoff\onoff\onoff...

\end{document}
```

[image: onoffonoffon]

Another way (was a now deleted separate answer)

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\onoff{\@onoff{on}{off}}
\def\@onoff #1#2{#1\def\onoff {\@onoff{#2}{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}

\onoff\onoff\onoff\onoff\onoff\onoff...

\end{document}
```

[image: onoffonoffon]

A third way

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\onoff {\onoroff{on\let\onoroff\@secondoftwo}{off\let\onoroff\@firstoftwo}}
\let\onoroff\@firstoftwo
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\onoff\onoff\onoff\onoff\onoff\onoff\onoff...

\onoff\onoff\onoff\onoff\onoff...

\end{document}
```

[image: more on off]

Comment: This is really clever :) Reminds me of http://heeeeeeeey.com

Comment: This is the answer I was about to write. While there is a lot of other possibilities, this one is definitely the most TeXy.

Comment: @SeanAllred I will adopt http://heeeeeeeey.com/ as a perfect alarm clock ... how many days before the asylum ?

Comment: @jfbu Two weeks – max :)

Answer (score 15):

Using `etoolbox` and bools and the greatest TikZ-foo i have ever produced.

[image: laurentOnOff]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newbool{volt}
\newcommand{\onoff}{%
    \ifbool{volt}{%
\boolfalse{volt}\candleOn\space ON}{%
    \booltrue{volt}\candleOff\space OFF}%
}
\newcommand{\candleOff}{\tikz \draw (0,0) rectangle
(.2,.8);}
\newcommand{\candleOn}{\begin{tikzpicture}\draw (0,0) rectangle
(.2,.8);\draw [fill=orange] (.1,.9) circle
[radius=.1];\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\onoff\par
\onoff\par
\onoff\par
\onoff\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: What advantage to `etoolbox`'s bools have (in functionality or readability) over the similar use of conditionals described by @egreg below (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/232062/1169)?  (Of course, egreg's answer doesn't include the stunning TikZ-foo.  :-) )

Comment: The advantage of one solution over the other is a matter of taste, imho. `etoolbox` gives a bunch of *higher-level* commands, no need for `@`-catcode hackery in most cases. Features like the ones described in the answers here are mostly needed by class/package authors, users just the functionality of the end result (on/off).

Answer (score 12):

Use a conditional

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifoff
\newcommand{\onoff}{%
  \relax\ifoff off\global\offfalse\else on\global\offtrue\fi
}

\begin{document}

\onoff

\onoff

\onoff

\end{document}
```

or a counter

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcount\offcount
\newcommand{\onoff}{%
  \relax
  \ifodd\offcount
    \global\advance\offcount 1
    off%
  \else
    \global\advance\offcount -1
    on%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\onoff

\onoff

\onoff

\end{document}
```

In both cases, if you want only local redefinitions, remove `\global`.

Note the starting `\relax`, necessary if you want to use `\onoff` in tables.

An abstract version, with the help of `etoolbox` that makes things a bit easier with toggles (it could be realized with conditionals).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\newalternatingcommand}[3]{%
  \newcommand{#1}{%
    \iftoggle{\string#1}
      {#2\global\togglefalse{\string#1}}
      {#3\global\toggletrue{\string#1}}%
  }%
  \newtoggle{\string#1}%
  \toggletrue{\string#1}%
}

\newalternatingcommand{\onoff}{on}{off}

\begin{document}

\onoff

\onoff

\onoff

\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the advantage / feature of `etoolbox's` `\iftoggle` vs. `\ifbool`?

Comment: @Manuel `\iftoggle` uses just one control sequence, while `\ifbool` uses three. But the advantage is mostly in the fact we can use `\string#1` in the argument of `\iftoggle` and a simpler syntax for the two cases.

Answer (score 8):

For example:

```
\def\onoffA{on\gdef\onoff{off\global\let\onoff=\onoffA}} \let\onoff=\onoffA

Test: \onoff, \onoff, \onoff, \onoff, \onoff, \onoff.

\bye
```