# Macros for redefining \maketitle

Tags: macros, titles, titling

I have a document with multiple `\maketitle` tags. I would like macros that will allow me to redefine the title with a single command. While the code below produces the output I want,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\maketitle{%
\par\textbf{\@title}%
\par{\@author}%
\par}
\makeatother

\title{First title}
\maketitle

\makeatletter
\def\maketitle{%
\par\textit{\@title}%
\par{\@author}%
\par}
\makeatother

\title{Second title}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

I really need to have macros that encapsulate the redefining of `\maketitle`. I would like something like this to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling}

\newcommand{\mytitleOne}{\makeatletter
\def\maketitle{%
\par\textbf{\@title}%
\par{\@author}% 
\par}
\makeatother}

\newcommand{\mytitleTwo}{\makeatletter
\def\maketitle{%
\par\textit{\@title}%
\par{\@author}%
\par}
\makeatother}


\begin{document}

\mytitleOne
\title{First title}
\maketitle


\mytitleTwo
\title{Second title}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are they in *ensured* alternating order? So *italic* definitely follows **bold** follows *italic*? If so .... [On/Off switch (redefine a macro at each use)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/232056)

Comment: This was just an example - in reality I'll be making other changes. But that is cool!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\settitlebf{%
\def\maketitle{%
    \par\textbf{\@title}%
    \par\@author%
    \par}
}

\newcommand\settitleit{%
\def\maketitle{%
    \par\textit{\@title}%
    \par\@author%
    \par}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\settitlebf
\title{Title One}
\maketitle

\settitleit
\title{Title Two}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't going to work for me. All of my documents use the syntax:
\title{My title}
\maketitlle
and I cannot really change this. I can only redefine before this happens

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: That is perfect!!! Thanks, I see what I was doing wrong now.